# Downloading from WebPage with Python

Tags: python, parsing, html, download

I'm a python newbie what I'm trying to do is create two scripts. One that downloads the webpage information and another scripts that downloads links and outputs a summary of the total number of links downloaded into a list.

**First script** (Download webpage)

```
import sys, urllib
def getWebpage(url):
    print '[*] getWebpage()'
    url_file = urllib.urlopen(url)
    page = url_file.read()
    return page
def main():
    sys.argv.append('http://www.funeralformyfat.tumblr.com)
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: webpage_get URL'
        return
    else:
        print getWebpage(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Second script** (downloads links and outputs a summary of the total number of links downloaded into a list.)

```
    import sys, urllib
def print_links(page):
    print '[*] print_links()'
    links = re.findall(r'\<a.*href\=.*http\:.+', page)
    links.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(links)), 'HyperLinks Found:'

    for link in links:
        print link

def main():
    sys.argv.append('http://www.funeralformyfat.tumblr.com')
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: webpage_links URL'
        return
        page = webpage_get.getWebpage(sys.argv[1])
        print_links(page)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My code runs however it doesn't return any links. Can anyone see the issue?.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you not make a smaller program that fails for the same reason? Find a minimal example, and it will be much easier for yourself and others to answer the question.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong from time to time ... I assume you want the print *inside* of the main function in the first script and the for loop *inside* of print_links. Also, for such a task you should consider to not use regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348 :-)

Comment: @cirosantilli The example here did not have much of a code & is fine. Sometimes full codes have to be posted in order to identify the errors.
PS - There was not much of a shortening that could be done for this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
print getWebpage(sys.argv[1]) <---- IndexError: list index out of range
```

The `sys.argv` has not yet updated (the append is in the `main` function which has **not** been called yet)

You should try the following & see the working for yourself.

```
import sys, urllib
def getWebpage(url):
    print '[*] getWebpage()'
    url_file = urllib.urlopen(url)
    page = url_file.read()
    return page
def main():
    sys.argv.append('http://www.funeralformyfat.tumblr.com')
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: webpage_get URL'
        return
    else:
        print getWebpage(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


NameError: name 'links' is not defined
```

This one occurs because you have `scoped` the `links` list outside of the function that defines that variable. The correct indentation would be

```
def print_links(page):
    print '[*] print_links()'
    links = re.findall(r'\<a.*href\=.*http\:.+', page)
    links.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(links)), 'HyperLinks Found:'

    for link in links:
        print link
```

Comment: If you look closer at the code provided you will see that the command line parameter is appended in the main() function.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Hi, thanks for the reply. I made changes but now I get an error on this line;

    sys.argv.append('http://www.funeralformyfat.tumblr.com')
NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined, do you know why this is?

Comment: Did you `import sys` before the execution of that line?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Hi, yeah. Sorry, I was being an idiot. I've updated it but now when I run it I don't get any links no matter what url I enter. I've updated my question with my new code. Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You need to verify your regex.